# Convert list of tuples into a dictionary with list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

**Input:**

```
original_list = [(5, 10, 8, 2, 3, 12, 'first', 'second', 2, 80, 75, 'third'), (8, 2, 8, 14, 7, 3, 'name', 'last', 2, 80, 75, 'block')]
```

**Output:**

```
new = {'specs':[(5, 10, 8, 2, 3, 12), (8, 2, 8, 14, 7, 3)], 'data': [('first', 'second', 2, 80, 75, 'third'), ('name', 'last', 2, 80, 75, 'block')]}
```

I need to separate the list of tuples (might be more than two shown above) into a dictionary with two keys: ***'specs'*** and ***'data'***

***'specs'*** values are supposed to be a list of tuples having first 6 elements from each tuple from original_list.

***'data'*** values are supposed to be a list of tuples having all the other elements from original_list.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Please read [ask]

Comment: @Chris The clear implicit question is "How do I do that?"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of list comprehensions and Bob's your uncle:

```
original_list = [
    (5, 10, 8, 2, 3, 12, "first", "second", 2, 80, 75, "third"),
    (8, 2, 8, 14, 7, 3, "name", "last", 2, 80, 75, "block"),
]
new = {
    "specs": [tuple(l[:6]) for l in original_list],
    "data": [tuple(l[6:]) for l in original_list],
}
print(new)
```

outputs

```
{
  'specs': [(5, 10, 8, 2, 3, 12), (8, 2, 8, 14, 7, 3)], 
  'data': [('first', 'second', 2, 80, 75, 'third'), ('name', 'last', 2, 80, 75, 'block')]
}
```

Comment: nice, you beat me too it ;) but you can ommit `tuple(..)`

Comment: No. That is needed to get the desired output.